# How to average a pandas data frame column before and after a given row based on some odd value n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
      Col A
 0      2
 1      3
 2      5
 3      4
 4      6
 5      2
 6      3
 7      1
 8      1
 9      7
```

and some odd numerical value like this

```
 n = 3
```

How do I average the value I'm replacing, the values before, and after based on half of my n. For n = 3 I would be averaging the value before and after. Such that I get a pandas dataframe like this:

```
      Col A   Col B
 0      2     np.nan
 1      3      3.33
 2      5       4
 3      4       5
 4      6       4
 5      2      3.67
 6      3       2
 7      1      2.5
 8      1       3
 9      7     np.nan
```

The first and last values are np.nan because there is not a value before/after them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rolling` with `center` option:

```
n = 3
df['Col A'].rolling(n, center=True).mean()
```

Output:

```
0         NaN
1    3.333333
2    4.000000
3    5.000000
4    4.000000
5    3.666667
6    2.000000
7    1.666667
8    3.000000
9         NaN
Name: Col A, dtype: float64
```